# Wildfly - how should I use a value held in a variable

Tags: jboss, wildfly

By using jboss-cli, I'm attempting to copy the connection-url of a datasource from one profile to another.

The purpose of this is to build a script to allow a third party to deploy our application, without prior knowledge of the database being used. The connection-url is just one of the values we need to copy.

I can, of course, read the source URL using this

```
/profile=financials/subsystem=datasources/data-source=coda:read-attribute(name=connection-url)
```

and I can assign that value to a variable (note the use of backquotes)

```
set db_url=`/profile=financials/subsystem=datasources/data-source=coda:read-attribute(name=connection-url)`
```

and successfully view the contents of that variable as a string

```
echo $db_url
```

However, when I try to use variable to write to another profile, like this

```
/profile=millennium/subsystem=datasources/data-source=coda:write-attribute(name=connection-url,value=$db_url)
```

I get this error: Expected [EXPRESSION, STRING] but was OBJECT"

```
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => {"domain-failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0097: Wrong type for 'connection-url'. Expected [EXPRESSION, STRING] but was OBJECT"}
,
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

So the question could also be this: how do I cast an object to a string in jboss-cli?

Thanks very much if you can help!

EDIT: We're using Wildfly version 23.

EDIT

I'd like to add that I've tried every (I think) permutation of the examples explained here: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-script/advanced-wildfly-cli-variables-and-aliases/

```
Using variables to set attributes
You can also use variables to set values of your configuration. Let’s see an example:

[standalone@localhost:9990 /] set MYVAR=foo
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /system-property=test:add(value="${MYVAR}")
However, the above command fails with:

{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0211: Cannot resolve expression '${MYVAR}'",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
That’s because you need to use a different format in your CLI to set values with variables. You need to include a colon (“:”) when setting attributes. That also allows setting a default value. The following will work:

/system-property=test:add(value="${MYVAR:}")
Finally, here is how to allow a default value for your variable:

/system-property=test:add(value="${MYVAR:default}")
```

.
.
.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem! I should have thought about using another attribute instead of the **connection-url**. I just tested the above with **user-name** instead, and it worked properly.
The problem above was caused by an equals sign (=) in the connection URL. It can be reproduced as follows and gives the same error message (Expected [EXPRESSION, STRING] but was OBJECT")

```
/profile=millennium/subsystem=datasources/data-source=coda:write-attribute(name=connection-url,value=aname=avalue)
```

So it boils down to escaping the equals (=) character, as in:

```
 /profile=millennium/subsystem=datasources/data-source=coda:write-attribute(name=connection-url,value=aname\=avalue)
```

Now I need to understand how to escape the contents of a variable, if it all possible.